# validar inputs dinámicos javascript

Tags: javascript

Lo que necesito es validar el formulario de la segunda sección de la pestaña.

Si hay algún campo vacío de los 4 que aparecen no ocultos o transparentes el botón debería decir hay campos 4 3 2 1 0 campos vacios
tengo este problema
al presionar botón este dice 2 inputs vacíos, siendo que son 4 inputs vacíos así por defecto
lo otro que quiero es que funcione el focus del input cuando pille un input vacío y que diga cada vez faltan datos a llenar al Lo que necesito es validar el formulario de la segunda sección de la pestaña.

Si hay algún campo vacío de los 4 que aparecen no ocultos o transparentes el botón debería estar deshabilitado.
como hacer para que me tome los inputs de abajo del botón guardar

```js
const id_prod = document.querySelector('#first-tab >#articulos>#productos_content>.tr >.id_n').textContent;
console.log(id_prod)

const tbody = document.querySelector('#second-tab >.shoppingCartItemsContainer > #form2 >#tabla >.tbody')
function updateCantidadNuevo(input) {
  if(input.checkValidity()){
   input.setAttribute("data-oldvalue", input.value);
  }
  else{
    input.value = input.getAttribute("data-oldvalue") || input.min;
  }
}
function add(id, cantidad=1){
  let input = document.querySelector('#shoppingCartItemQuantity_'+id);
  input.value= input.valueAsNumber + cantidad;
  updateCantidadNuevo(input);
  
console.log(id,input);
}



const addToShoppingCartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#first-tab > #articulos > tbody > tr > .td > .button')
console.log(addToShoppingCartButtons)
addToShoppingCartButtons.forEach((addToCartButton) => {
  addToCartButton.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked);
  
  
  
  
  
  function addToCartClicked(event) {
  const button = event.target;
  
  const item = button.closest('.tr');

  const id_prod = item.querySelector('.id_n').textContent
  const cantidad_disponible = item.querySelector('.cantidad_disponible').textContent;
  const talla = item.querySelector('.talla').textContent;

  
  addItemToShoppingCart(id_prod,  cantidad_disponible, talla);
}
function addItemToShoppingCart(id_prod,cantidad_disponible,talla) {
    

  if(cantidad_disponible!=0){
  const elementsTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('title');

  for (let i = 0; i < elementsTitle.length; i++) {
    if (elementsTitle[i].innerText === id_prod) {
     
      return;
    }
  }

  const tr = document.createElement('tr')
    tr.classList.add('ItemCarrito')
     tr.setAttribute("id", `tr_${id_prod}`);

  Content = `
     <th scope="row">${id_prod}</th>

     <td class="table__productos">
     <input id="id_productos_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${id_prod}" class="id_productos"
    style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">

       <h6 id="title_${id_prod}" class="title" hidden>${id_prod}</h6>
     </td>

    
     <td class="table__cantidad_disponible">
     <input id="cantidad_disponible_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${cantidad_disponible}" class="cantidad_disponible"
     style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
      
    </td>

    <td class="table__talla">
    <input id="talla_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${talla}" class="talla"
   style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
      
     </td>

   



    
    
    <td class="table__cantidad">
                <input id="shoppingCartItemQuantity_${id_prod}" max="${cantidad_disponible}" oninput="updateCantidad(this)" class="shopping-cart-quantity-input shoppingCartItemQuantity_${id_prod}" type="number"
                    value="1" min="1">
                
                </td>
         <td class="table__precio">
     <input required id="precio_${id_prod}" type="text" class="precio"   onchange="CarritoTotalmio()" min="0">
      
     </td>

     <td class="table__delete">
     <button class="delete btn btn-danger">x</button>
      
    </td>
     `
   
    
   tr.innerHTML = Content 
     tbody.append(tr)
}else{
  console.log("tiene un 0 imposible agregar");
}
}


});


var a = document.getElementById("guardardatos");

var b = document.querySelectorAll("input"); //Buscamos todos los inputs que existan en el documento
console.log(b)
a.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault() // le asignamos al boton enviar el evento onclick
var con = 0; //iniciamos una variable que incrementaremos si hay vacios.
  for(var c in b) //Iteramos todos los inputs que encontramos
  {
    var d = b[c];
    if(typeof d == "object")
    { 
      if(d.value == "" ) // Si existe algun campo vacio entonces incrementamos el contador
      {
        con ++;  
      }
    }
  }
  if(con >0)
  { 
    alert("Tienes "+con+ " campos vacios");}
  else{
   alert('todo lleno')
   }
})
```

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
input[type=number] { -moz-appearance:textfield; }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled-2</title>
  
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
   
</head>
<body>



  

<section class="section">
      <div class="tabs">
         <ul class="tabs-menu">
          <li class="is-active" data-target="first-tab"><a>Tab one</a></li>
          <li data-target="second-tab"><a>Tab two</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content" id="first-tab">

      <table id="articulos"class="table">
        <thead>
           
            <tr>
            
            <TH>id </TH>
            <TH>id del producto</TH>
            <TH>cantidad_disponible</TH>
            <TH>talla zapatos</TH>
                <TH>Añadir</TH>
              <TH>Añadir</TH>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody  id="productos_content">
             <tr class="tr">
         
            
            <td class="id_n">15<td>
            <td class="cantidad_disponible"> 3</td>
            <td class="talla"> 36</td>
              
<td class="td"><button id="15" onclick="add(15)"   class="button">Añadir</button></td>
  
        </tr> 
       
       <tr class="tr">
         
            
            <td class="id_n">1<td>
            <td class="cantidad_disponible"> 7</td>
            <td class="talla"> 40</td>
          
<td class="td"><button id="15" onclick="add(1)"   class="button">Añadir</button></td>
    
        </tr> 
        </tbody>
        </table>
    
          </div>



      <div class="tab-content" id="second-tab">
      <div class="shopping-cart-items shoppingCartItemsContainer">
      <form id="form2" >
<input type="text" name="campo" id="campo"class="form-control" required>
                
                    <input type="text" id="content" class="form-control">
<input type="submit" id="guardardatos" value="Guardar"  />
   

      <table id="tabla" class="table">
 
            <tr>
            <TH>id</TH>
            <TH>id del producto</TH>   
            <TH>cantidad_disponible</TH>
            <TH>talla zapatos</TH>          
            <TH>Añadir </TH>    
            </tr>
               <tbody id="carrito_content" class="tbody">
               
        </tbody>
    </table>

      <div class="float-right">
      Total:<input type="text" id="resultado_total" value="0" disabled > </input>

        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>

<script>
    const tabSystem = {
    init(){
        document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-menu').forEach(tabMenu => {
            Array.from(tabMenu.children).forEach((child, ind) => {
                child.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    tabSystem.toggle(child.dataset.target);
                });
                if(child.className.includes('is-active')){
                    tabSystem.toggle(child.dataset.target);
                }
            });
        });
    },
    toggle(targetId){
        document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content').forEach(contentElement=>{
            contentElement.style.display = contentElement.id === targetId ? 'block' : 'none';
            document.querySelector(`[data-target="${contentElement.id}"]`).classList[contentElement.id === targetId ? 'add' : 'remove']('is-active');
        })
    },
};
// use it
tabSystem.init()
</script>


</html>
```

Comment: La validación la está haciendo sobre los dos campos que estan arriba, junto al botón de buscar. Deberías revisar por ahí. No miré el código porque es muy extenso para seguirlo.

Answer (score 0):

veamos como validamos dinamicamente los campos:

1. Agrega una función `validarFormulario()` para verificar los campos vacíos y actualizar el estado del botón de guardar:

```
function validarFormulario() {
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#form2 input");
    let camposVacios = 0;
  
    inputs.forEach((input) => {
        if (input.value.trim() === "") {
            camposVacios++;
        }
    });
  
    const botonGuardar = document.getElementById("guardardatos");
  
    if (camposVacios > 0) {
        botonGuardar.disabled = true;
        botonGuardar.value = `Hay ${camposVacios} campos vacíos`;
    } else {
        botonGuardar.disabled = false;
        botonGuardar.value = "Guardar";
    }
}
```

2. Agrega un evento input a cada input dentro del formulario para llamar a la función `validarFormulario()` y verificar los cambios en tiempo real:

```
inputs.forEach((input) => {
    input.addEventListener("input", validarFormulario);
});
```

3. Llama a la función `validarFormulario()` una vez que se ha cargado la página, para establecer el estado inicial del botón de guardar:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", validarFormulario);
```

Entonces la función `validarFormulario()` se encargará de verificar si hay campos vacíos en los inputs y actualizará el estado del botón de guardar en consecuencia. Al agregar o modificar el contenido de los inputs, se llamará a la función automáticamente para reflejar los cambios en el estado del botón.

Si necesitas realizar una validación más completa o específica para cada campo, puedes ajustar la lógica en la función `validarFormulario()` según tus requisitos.

***Este es un ejemplo funcional del la implementacion del Script:***

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            const form = document.getElementById("form2");
            const inputs = form.querySelectorAll("input");
            const botonGuardar = document.getElementById("guardardatos");

            form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
                event.preventDefault();
                // Aquí puedes realizar las acciones necesarias al enviar el formulario
            });

            inputs.forEach((input) => {
                input.addEventListener("input", validarFormulario);
            });

            validarFormulario();

            function validarFormulario() {
                let camposVacios = 0;

                inputs.forEach((input) => {
                    if (input.value.trim() === "") {
                        camposVacios++;
                    }
                });

                if (camposVacios > 0) {
                    botonGuardar.disabled = true;
                    botonGuardar.value = `Hay ${camposVacios} campos vacíos`;
                } else {
                    botonGuardar.disabled = false;
                    botonGuardar.value = "Guardar";
                }
            }
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Validación de Inputs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="section">
        <div class="tabs">
            <ul class="tabs-menu">
                <li class="is-active" data-target="first-tab"><a>Tab one</a></li>
                <li data-target="second-tab"><a>Tab two</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content" id="first-tab">
            <!-- Contenido de la primera pestaña -->
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content" id="second-tab">
            <div class="shopping-cart-items shoppingCartItemsContainer">
                <form id="form2">
                    <input type="text" name="campo" id="campo" class="form-control" required>
                    <input type="text" id="content" class="form-control">
                    <input type="submit" id="guardardatos" value="Guardar">
                    <table id="tabla" class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>id</th>
                                <th>id del producto</th>
                                <th>cantidad_disponible</th>
                                <th>talla zapatos</th>
                                <th>Añadir</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="carrito_content" class="tbody">
                            <!-- Contenido de los elementos agregados dinámicamente -->
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="float-right">
                        Total: <input type="text" id="resultado_total" value="0" disabled>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola buenas, al momento de agregar los inputs dinamicos esto de del nu,ero de los campos vacios no me aumenta siempre me queda en 2 campos vacios ya que agregue 2 productos a la tabla

Comment: @FelipeDeveloper tienes que dar un mejor ejemplo de que hiciste... edita tu post. a mi me esta funcionando como en el ejemplo al darle ejecutar

Comment: eso es lo que no logro hacer, es con inputs dinámicos